# Form submit event does'nt work as it should(Meteor)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a form in meteor, when I submit it, I want to route to a different template. But it doesnt work some how.

The path of form is: localhost:3000/dateForm

input to form is date, month and year of birthday(irrelevant). But when it submit the form(with submit form event in place and having Router.go("/display") present) it just shows "http://localhost:3000/dateform?day=25&month=9&year=1996" in address bar(25, 9, 1996 being the inputs in form) and just shows the same form page.

How do I make the app route to different template on submit event?

The html code in main.html:

```
<template name="dateFormPage">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1 class="display-1">Enter Your Birthday</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Day" name="day">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Month(number)" name="month">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Year" name="year">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
  </form>
</template>

<template name="display">
  abcderfght
</template>
```

the code in main.js

```
Template.dateFormPage.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    var day=event.target.day.value.parseInt();
    var month=event.target.month.value.parseInt()-1;
    var year=event.target.year.value.parseInt();
    var today=new Date();
    var toDate=today.getDate();
    var toMonth=today.getMonth();
    var toYear=today.getFullYear();

    function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
    }

    var month_diff_raw=monthDiff(new Date(day, month, year), new Date(toDate, toMonth, toYear));

    Session.set("year_diff", month_diff_raw/12);

  },
});
```

console.log() also doesnt work in event handler.

What's gone wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very high chance you should simply prevent the form from being actually submitted:

```js
event.preventDefault();
```

When user presses your `submit` button, besides calling your event listener, the browser also submits the form, which default action is to reload the current page.

This probably explains why your `console.log` does not seem to work: the console is cleared when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Thank you ghybs so much. This was the only thing missing that was making app behave aberrantly.